# removeFromSuperview EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, exc-bad-access

I've developed a game for iPhone starting from iOS 6.0.

It works fine on my 5S running on iOS 7.1 but when testing it on my old 3GS with iOS 6.1.3, it crash with a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS code:0" when trying to remove some custom UIView from superview.

I logged my custom view and it's superview (that are not nil), but nothing to do it work !

Also tried logging my views and superviews with lldb command and it confirms they are not nil.

Any idea ?? Can't understand how it could work on iOS7 and not on iOS6 !

Here the code when I get the error :

```
- (void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent{
    if(parent == nil){
        for (LevelNumberView *button in self.levelButtons) {
            if(self.view && [self.view.subviews containsObject:button]){
                NSLog(@"-- button:%@", button);
                [button removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
        self.levelButtons = nil;
        [self.titleView removeFromSuperview];
        self.titleView = nil;
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
        self.delegate = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it look like a stack overflow (infinite loop), or a bad memory access (try running the Zombies instrument)? Those are two common causes of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: By the way, are you using ARC?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ARC.
It's not an infinite loop and I can't use Zombies instrument ! (Probably due to the fact it's on 3GS ... It works on 5S)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call `removeFromSuperview` on any valid UIView (whether it has a superview or not) so that should not cause an error. My guess would be one of the pointers (that is not nil) is pointing to a released object.

Comment: I don’t think that’s the problem. I just tested this, and it didn’t crash (nor did it print anything): `NSArray *array = nil; for (id obj in array) { NSLog(@"hi"); }`

Comment: You're right. In that case your code posted is fine and your problem is probably one of the pointers (that is not nil) is pointing to a released object.

Comment: Ok, but what is strange is that it doesn't crash on iPhone 5S running iOS 7.1 ! And if my NSArray has strong reference, items inside can be released automatically ?

Comment: Moreover, if I comment the loop, I have the same issue on [self.view removeFromSuperview]; ... self.view shouldn't be already released at that time ??!

Answer (score 0):

I fix the same issue using check the superview before remove it :

```
if(self.loadingView.superview){
        [self.loadingView removeFromSuperview];
    }
```